# GLthread and RenderThread in systrace

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, rendering, systrace

When i see the **systrace** for gallery app,I see two threads in the gallery process -  **GLthread** and **RenderThread**. How are these two different?

Comment: The threads are named by the applications and services, not by systrace, so your question is meaningless without more context.

Comment: @fadden  - is it enough or shall i give more information?

Comment: It is. Now you need someone familiar with the internals of the gallery app to explain what each of those threads does. Alternatively, if you have a developer device (with `ro.debuggable` set to 1) you can just attach DDMS and double-click on the threads while the app runs to see stack trace snapshots. If you do that several times you'll get a pretty good sense for what each thread is up to.

Comment: Thanks! Will try that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm checking a systrace result which is same as yours.
There're RenderThread as well as GLThread and after some search I found out that my RenderThread is different w/ their.

For example look at this [article](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render#rendering_performance_renderthread): There're `DrawFrame` or `Texture upload` functions inner RenderThread.

But my systrace file shows that this stuff comes on the GLThread and my RenderThread just running but without any more details. So my conclusion is that focus on your logic stuff find out some key info such as: *onDrawFrame*, *eglSwapBuffers*, *dequeueBuffer*... to find out the Thread that really doing stuff.